# How to run Ubuntu OS  in Windows off USB Disk without rebooting or installing on PC

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, usb, virtualbox

Please help me install Ubuntu OS latest build (12.04) on a Kingston Data Traveler USB 8 GB (FAT32)

without having to restart and boot from the USB drive.

I want  Ubuntu to load & run inside Win XP 32 Bit OS & Win 7 Home Premium 64 Bit OS whenever, I insert my USB stick in any port, but I don't want to actually install it on the machine , I want it to run portably off the drive

Like how Win 7 Professional OS & Win 7 Ultimate OS have Win XP Mode for legacy software & is able to access, modify & save all file & folders of the host machine

But in this case I want to use the USB Stick, please tell me if its possible to access the files & folders of the local machine?

Specifically:

1. How do I install Virtualbox 32bit on the USB drive?
2. If I Start the Virtualbox from the USB drive, then,
3. How do I create a new virtual machine for Ubuntu, and save it's virtual harddrive to the USB ?
4. Could I use [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) out of curiosity?

[image]

Comment: I hope @Sepero you are here ?????

Comment: @Brandon Kreisel, Thanx for the Edit !!!!!

Comment: [Portable VirtualBox](http://www.vbox.me/)

Comment: **@Bob** Thanx, then, how do I install Ubuntu OS on USB, which one 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu OS ???????

Answer (score 0):

I use [Microsoft Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4580) with [Daemon Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite). Daemon Tools allows me to just boot up the .iso from a virtual cd, then once you boot up you can just install Ubuntu on to the virtual drive (which you create with Virtual PC).

Comment: **@Peter Maxwell, Thanx**